# Why does a pointer to a local variable escape to the heap?

Tags: go, heap-memory

Here is my go environment:

```
[lorneli@localhost GoTest]$ go version
go version go1.9 linux/amd64
```

Here is my program:

```
package main

type request struct {
    ID string
    size uint32
    off uint64
}

func main() {
    r := request{}
    iter := interface{}(&r) // &r escapes to heap
    iters := make([]interface{}, 0)
    iters = append(iters, iter)
}
```

I allocate a `request` instance and convert the pointer of it to `interface{}`.
But when analysing with flag `-gcflags "-m"` , I found out the instance escapes 
to heap when converting. Why this happens?

Here is analysing result:

```
[lorneli@localhost GoTest]$ go build -gcflags "-m"
# _/mnt/hgfs/vmfolder/workspace/GoTest
./main.go:9:6: can inline main
./main.go:11:21: (interface {})(&r) escapes to heap
./main.go:11:22: &r escapes to heap
./main.go:10:15: moved to heap: r
./main.go:12:15: main make([]interface {}, 0) does not escape
```

I think this case doesn't match any cases listed on ["Go Escape Analysis Flaws"](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CxgUBPlx9iJzkz9JWkb6tIpTe5q32QDmz8l0BouG0Cw/preview#heading=h.jf07ptqo2xbk).

Comment: My take is that this case is covered by the "Flow through fields" case in the document you referred to: a value of type `interface{}` is a struct of two pointer fields. Still, note that the document is pretty old (2015) so I'd ask this question on the mailing list to possibly solicit a refresher on these matters.

Comment: This is an implementation detail to be asked on golang-nuts.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll ask on mailing list later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplify your example. Analyze with `-gcflags='-m -m'`.

**Example 1**:

```
package main

func main() {
    var v int
    s := make([]*int, 0)
    s = append(s, &v) // &v escapes to heap
}
```

Output:

```
$ go version
go version devel +df8c2b905b Tue Mar 6 06:13:17 2018 +0000 linux/amd64
$ go run -gcflags='-m -m' esc.go
# command-line-arguments
./esc.go:3:6: can inline main as: func() { var v int; v = <N>; s := make([]*int, 0); s = append(s, &v) }
./esc.go:6:16: &v escapes to heap
./esc.go:6:16:  from append(s, &v) (appended to slice) at ./esc.go:6:12
./esc.go:4:6: moved to heap: v
./esc.go:5:11: main make([]*int, 0) does not escape
$
```

---

Escape analysis determines whether any references to a value escape the function in which the value is declared. A reference to the variable `v`, declared in function `main`, escapes as an argument to function `append`: `&v escapes to heap from append(s, &v)`, `moved to heap: v`.

---

**Example 2**:

```
package main

func main() {
    var v int
    lc := 1
    s := make([]*int, lc)
    s[0] = &v
}

$ go run -gcflags='-m -m' esc2.go
./esc2.go:3:6: can inline main as: func() { var v int; v = <N>; lc := 1; s := make([]*int, lc); s[0] = &v }
./esc2.go:6:11: make([]*int, lc) escapes to heap
./esc2.go:6:11:     from make([]*int, lc) (too large for stack) at ./esc2.go:6:11
./esc2.go:7:9: &v escapes to heap
./esc2.go:7:9:  from s[0] (slice-element-equals) at ./esc2.go:7:7
./esc2.go:4:6: moved to heap: v
$
```

---

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

`make` for a slice returns a slice descriptor `struct` (pointer to underlying array, length, and capacity) and allocates an underlying slice element array. The underlying array is generally allocated on the heap: `make([]*int, lc) escapes to heap from make([]*int, lc)`.

`s[0] = &v` stores a reference to the variable `v` (`&v`) in the underlying array on the heap: `&v escapes to heap from s[0] (slice-element-equals)`, `moved to heap: v`. The reference remains on the heap, after the function ends and its stack is reclaimed, until the underlying array is garbage collected.

If the `make` slice capacity is a small (compile time) constant, `make([]*int, 1)` in your example, the underlying array may be allocated on the stack. However, escape analysis does not take this into account.

Comment: @perter Thanks. I change code to:  `s := make([]*int, 1)   s[1] = &v`. The variable still escapes. Is that because analysis thinks pointers in slice may escape out of function.

Comment: I find a blog [go-escape-analysis](http://www.agardner.me/golang/garbage/collection/gc/escape/analysis/2015/10/18/go-escape-analysis.html). From its penultimate paragraph, " Remember that slices and maps are actually just Go structs with pointers to heap-allocated memory". I think this may explain why the variable still escapes.

Comment: Thanks for your patience!